# Angularjs select ng-model binding for object

Tags: html, angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-model

I want to have a select for array of objects.[example](http://plnkr.co/edit/pr34EuflEQRDX26rUfXU?p=preview) But somehow , I am not able to access properties of selected object.

js---

```
 $scope.test1={};
 $scope.test = [{'name':'test1'},{'name':'test2'},{'name':'test3'}];
```

html--

```
<select style="width:100px;height:25px;" ng-model="test1">
   <option  ng-repeat="attribute in test" value="{{attribute}}">{{attribute['name']}}</option>
</select>
{{test1}}
{{test1.name}}
```

here , test1.name comes blank.

Comment: you should use `ng-options` in this case rather than `ng-repeat`.  `option` tags can only be bound to strings, so your `test1` in this case is not an object, it is literally the string representation of the object.  `ng-options` is designed to overcome this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it using [ngOpions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) this way.It  gives proper controll than [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
<select style="width:100px;height:25px;" ng-model="test1"  
     ng-options="attribute.name  for  attribute in test">
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rAhdWy1xeMBFM4njZrj4?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `select` `value` is interpreted as string. Not as object. And of course strings don't have `name` property. You can use `ng-options` if you want your values to contain the whole object. [Read the documentation here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)